# Lyx - disable auto-jumping to cursor when clicking on math/table/etc.?

Tags: lyx

As the title says I don't want to have *any* auto-scrolling/jumping etc. when writing my documents. Is there a way to disable that *feature*? I'd go so far to recompile and edit source code myself if there is one available because I can **not** use the program in its current state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome. I don't really understand what you mean. I tried with a dummy document, and there is no scrolling if I click on a math environment, or a table. Could you try to clarify? (For that matter, the code is available: https://www.lyx.org/Development)

Comment: I think I've experienced a similar annoyance when the cursor moves into a table/math and that triggers a toolbar which changes the vertical spacing and moves everything around. Are things better if you disable the auto-toolbars, so that they are not triggered based on cursor placement?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried to be as clear as possible and described exactly what happens. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: And @scottkosty indeed found the culprit. If I disable auto-toolbars the jumping does not trigger. Which is kind of a workaround though because I do like the auto-toolbars.

Comment: @Lux I agree that it's a workaround. Perhaps you can make an answer that mentions the work around and then points to an enhancement request you make at https://www.lyx.org/trac ? It would be nice if that behavior could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @scottkosty a workaround for this problem (partially) is to disable all auto-toolbars. In some cases e.g. selecting a table that is partially offscreen will still auto-scroll to bring the whole table in focus.

The problem (apparently only for a small number of people) seems to have been mentioned 9/6 years ago and has not received any attention since then.

https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8894

https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7457